# apache cordova visual studio 2015: Unable to include some files and folders e.g bower_components files and folder

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-2015

When I include files and folder it rolls back those files and excluded automatically

here's in screenshot. i tried many times but not succeeded.

[image: Image here]

Comment: I solved this problem after restart my project and include again these files and folder. Successfully included.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: Restart the visual studio (application) will solved this issue.